# Remove whitespaces and extract text between specific characters in Python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a part of code which obtain by `text = soup.find("table", attrs={"id":"mse_new"}).find("div", attrs={"class":"rmktxt"})`:

```
<div class="rmktxt">
                     1. The project is located on the northeast side of the intersection of Liancheng Road and Baiqian Road, with a land area of 27846 square meters, of which 23847 square meters are residential land, 3999 square meters of public green space, and the total construction area is temporarily estimated to be 60117 square meters (including The above-ground building area is 44117 square meters... <a class="login-btn" href="javascript:">Click to view details</a>
</div>
```

Now I want extract the following text part from it:

```
1. The project is located on the northeast side of the intersection of Liancheng Road and Baiqian Road, with a land area of 27846 square meters, of which 23847 square meters are residential land, 3999 square meters of public green space, and the total construction area is temporarily estimated to be 60117 square meters (including The above-ground building area is 44117 square meters...
```

How could I do that in Python? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can use `.text.strip()`

**Ex:**

```
text = soup.find("table", attrs={"id":"mse_new"}).find("div", attrs={"class":"rmktxt"}).text.strip()
```

**Note:** Using Regex on HTML is very bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for this improvement, this is the aswer i'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

The solution I used:

```
# text = soup.find("table", attrs={"id":"mse_new"}).find("div", attrs={"class":"rmktxt"})
text = str(text)
text = " ".join(text.split())
result = re.search('<div class="rmktxt">(.*)<a class="login-btn"', text)
print(result.group(1))
```

Out:

```
1. The project is located on the northeast side of the intersection of Liancheng Road and Baiqian Road, with a land area of 27846 square meters, of which 23847 square meters are residential land, 3999 square meters of public green space, and the total construction area is temporarily estimated to be 60117 square meters (including The above-ground building area is 44117 square meters...
```